# iOS safari reader view not showing site correctly

Tags: html, ios, safari

iOS safari reader view looks weird. It shows headline and underline of a video and a lot of white space. Also the title is double. It also shows the word advertisement when there is an ad in the original page.

Does anybody know which keywords triggers the reader view in iOS and how to customize it?
I found absolutely nothing to this topic at all...

thanks

Comment: Does iOS Safari Reader view ever show correctly?

Comment: In my experience, Safari Reader view will show more or less correctly for HTML4 era content and the operating system does not matter. The better the content follows HTML5 spec the lower the probability that Reader works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there's no official way to customize the viewer. It's technically implemented as Safari Extension and simply injects JavaScript in your page to do its magic. For more information, see the extracted source at https://github.com/amumu/safari-reader-js

Official Apple documentation does mention [class `SafariReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safarireader) but as far as I know, there's no way to access that from the content (server emitted HTML or JavaScript). If you could access `SafariReader` it would provide required methods to better control it. Another interesting class would be [`SafariContentViewer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariextensions/safaricontentreader). If you could somehow access SafariReader, you could then follow the documentation: [Working with Safari Reader](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingWiththeReader/WorkingWiththeReader.html).